# Question about web browser and file downloading/uploading?

Tags: networking, network-programming, browser

I am wondering how a web browser work. I have just finished reviewing my network text book. Below is my wild imagination and questions.

Web browser usually works with HTTP protocol. So the 1st question will be:

- Who is responsible to support the HTTP protocol?

I think the HTTP protocol should be implemented in the web browser, while the TCP, UDP, IP, etc protocols should be implemented in OS. And this is why the HTTP protocol is called an ***Application-Level Protocol***. (*Correct me if I am wrong.*)

Get back to the HTTP communication scenario.

**On the client side**:

When an address is typed into the web browser, the web browser will choose proper HTTP method and fabricate a complete HTTP request. This HTTP request is nothing but pure ASCII text. Then the browser choose a private port number and use the TCP protocol to send the text bit stream to the server. During this process, DNS query is made if the URL is not a IP address.

**On the server side**:

When some TCP packet arrives at the server, it is examined to see if it is targeted at 80 port. If so, it is delivered to the server process, and now the TCP protocol has finished its job and it's time for the server program to come into action. The server program needs to implement the HTTP protocol so that it could parse the client browser's HTTP request extracted from the TCP packet. And then return necessary HTML file back to client. These HTML file could be static or dynamically generated with technology like ASP.NET.

In the case of **uploading and downloading file**, I think there can be 2 different approaches.

- No matter what format the file is, we could encode them as Base64 string, thus we could embed them as part of the web page. I am wondering if it is possible to encode a jpeg file as Base64 string and embed it in a web page.(*Correct me if I am wrong.*)
- The other approach is not to embed the file content in the web page, but to directly use TCP connections to transmit it. This approach doesn't require Base64 encoding and should have better performance. (*Correct me if I am wrong.*)

I may have chosen a bad title for the above questions and statement.

I hope the moderator wouldn't take this question as off topic.

Many thanks.

Comment: I think you've combined several questions into one. I'm not sure where to even start answering, other than giving a few links to RFCs for example. And honestly, you're also pushing the bounds of what is on topic. I wonder if there is a networking stack exchange...

Comment: I agree with you. I have to say this is like a brain storm suddenly hit me. And I don't have enough time to divide them into separate topics before they fade away. Sorry for inconvenience.

Comment: Not sure what the answer is, but this could be incredible if all resources were part of a single file, then divided and assigned on the fly, could change the web entirely! Get to the bottom of it!

Answer (score 2):

I saw some things I beleive are not 100% percent correct...

> Then the browser choose a private port number and use the TCP protocol to send the text bit stream to the server.

Here it seems you're saying that the browser chooses a local port and assigns it to the TCP stream being opened, which is not correct, since the OS is what keeps track of used/unused  ports, and assigns ports to streams when a new connection is being established.

> When some TCP packet arrives at the server, it is examined to see if it is targeted at 80 port. If so, it is delivered to the server process, and now the TCP protocol has finished its job and it's time for the server program to come into action.

Here I see two details: First, from the text it seems a single TCP packet contains all the HTTP message, which may not be true (it may be split in many TCP packets for a number of reasons, but mainly because packets have a fixed maximum length, and the message may be longer than that length). Second, it is assumed that the web server runs on port 80, which is normally the case, but not always true, for example I believe the default port for the Apache Tomcat Web Server is 8080, and in most cases the port the web server listens to can be configured (I don't know any webserver that is 100% fixed to a special port).

Finally, when you say

> When an address is typed into the web browser, the web browser will choose proper HTTP method and fabricate a complete HTTP request.

I think that in this particular case (the user typed an address and pressed enter) the browser will always choose the GET method, as POST is used when submitting information to the server.

HTTP is quite simple at first, but has many details that add complexity to it. I am far from being an expert on the subject, but maybe this can help further :) http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2616.html

Answer (score 1):

TCP is a transport protocol. It describes how to get a stream of arbitrary data from one network point to another. This is something almost every networking app will need to do, so it makes sense to have this built into the OS (it need not be, mind, but it is by standard on every popular OS now).

Having data exchange between two machines/applications isn't quite enough though - they need to agree on how the data will be formatted (a protocol). There are many different ways data can be formatted, and the best way depends on the kind of data and the kind of application.

HTTP is designed specifically as a request/response protocol on top of TCP, but it could run over any transport protocol. You don't need to base64 data in HTTP, since the recipient need not inspect the data payload to find when it ends, the payload can contain anything. HTTP uses a length header to inform the recipient how much data the message contains.

Other applications might choose other protocols to sit on top of TCP. For example HTTP has no facility to allow a server to send a message to the client, except in response to a request. Another protocol would be better suited if this is needed, this is kind of what websockets are trying to achieve.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I learn that it is necessary to separate *what to send (application-level protocol)* and *how to send(transport-level protocol)*. And I found a good article about using XML as the application-level protocol.http://www.developer.com/xml/article.php/1380861/Using-XML-as-an-Application-Level-Protocol.htm

Comment: That appears to be a good article that describes the issues of protocol design. For XML over the wire, take a look at the XMPP protocol ( http://xmpp.org/ ). Being involved in the XMPP community myself has taught me quite a bit about protocol design and networking, and I've found that I like it a lot :)

Comment: Don't disregard http as an application level protocol. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer is popular.

Comment: Far from disregarding. However not all applications fit the REST architecture, and many people make the mistake of not seeing that :)

Answer (score 0):

Solely in response to your questions regarding file uploads/downloads:

If restricted to HTTP, file downloads normally occur by a browser following a link to a downloadable file, upon which a GET request is sent for that content. The data is sent over the HTTP connection in the same way a web page is sent.

For a file upload, the most common case is that of a form submission; the user chooses a file as part of a form. Upon the submit button being clicked, the browser sends a POST to the server. As part of the POST a delimiter string is assigned, and the file's bytes are sent in between the delimiter string so the server can recognize it.

There are other options, but these are most common.

There is no built-in-to-HTTP way to support loading a file as a base64 string. Files included in web pages, like pictures, are requested in separate requests: each resource is retrieved with a GET request. However, it would be possible to parse data from an included base64 string using javascript and reassemble it into a resource. This wouldn't be done because of the complex code and processing that would need to be done, but is possible.

As for your analysis of the network communication, it seems pretty much correct to me.